# 45 days visa-free entry to Phuket, Thailand

Tags: visas, thailand

Fliege in 2 wochen für 42 Tage über Sandbox nach Phuket.45 Tage exemption ist zurück gesetzt auf 30 Tage.Mir fehlen  12 Tage .Für ein Visum ist die Zeit zu knapp.Ich kann vor Ort eine Visumverlängerung bekommen oder 500 Bhat pro Tag zahlen .Kein Problem .Aber lässt mich Emirates überhaupt mit dem nicht vorhandenen Visum fliegen?Macht die Immigration Probleme und gewährt die 30 Tage Visumfrei nicht weil der Rückflug zu spät ist?

English translation:

> I'm flying in 2 weeks for 42 days via Sandbox to Phuket. The 45-day exemption is reduced to 30 days. My trip is 12 days too long. Time is too short for a visa. I can get a visa extension on site or pay 500 Bhat per day. No problem. But will Emirates even let me fly without a visa? Will immigration cause problems and refuse the 30-day visa-free period because the return flight is too late?

Comment: What does 'Sandbox' mean?

Comment: @RichardBeasley: https://www.thaiembassy.com/travel-to-thailand/no-quarantine-phuket-sandbox-plan  There are a few quarantine-free pockets in Thailand, which are easier to access than Thailand proper. These are called sandbox (and have specific rules)

Answer (score 2):

Contact Emirates to be sure of their policy.  In general though, there's no trouble boarding flights if you have a passport for a country which Thailand offers VOA.  At the checking counter, most agents will ask you and check that you are eligible for VOA.
From my experience regarding visas, Thai customs only bother you on the way out.  It's your responsibility to extend your visa or leave before it expires.  If you don't, you're paying the fee when you do leave and/or blacklisted from returning to Thailand.